# SQL Upon finding duplicate key, replace entire entry

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have an insert query for MySQL that looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (foo, bar, fooo, baar, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

It is used in a script to migrate some columns and keeps encountering duplicate primary keys. (Old database was awful and poorly maintained).

Is there a way I can just tell it to replace the whole offending row with the current values tossing out the old stuff entirely? I know there is an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command, but I don't know if it would help me as all I've seen it used for is incrementing.

ANSWER:  `INSERT INTO table (foo, bar, fooo, baar, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo=?, bar=?, fooo=?, baar=?, etc=?`

Keep in mind that you have to add the values in the referenced array again to account for the extra question marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MySQL manual:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY
>   UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a
>   UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE
>   of the old row is performed.

What you said:

> Is there a way I can just tell it to
>   replace the whole offending row with
>   the current values tossing out the old
>   stuff entirely?

Conclusion: why don't you just try it? It seems it does exactly what you want.

---

Edit: Since you haven't provided any examples of what you were trying to do, I'll use some from MySQL's website.

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Or if you want something that relates more to real world:

INSERT INTO table(int_field, str_field, float_field) VALUES (15, 'some string', '1.22') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE int_field = 15, str_field = 'some_string', float_field = '1.22';

Comment: I think maybe you are assuming too much about my SQL knowledge. All of the examples I've seen just do something like `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE foo = foo+1` or something like that. Is it allowed to do something like `INSERT INTO table (foo, bar, fooo, baar, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE (foo, bar, fooo, baar, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)`? When I try this I just get errors. Should it be working?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table (foo, bar, fooo, baar, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)` Is an example of what I am trying to do: you use questions marks that refer to an array of values (in my case the array grabs values from a resultSet, I just figured seeing the question mark you would have made the connection). Anyway, thanks for trying to help at least, I figured it out by trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

`on duplicate key update` should work, as should a `replace` statement.